# Django can't connect to mysql via docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have an application using Django and MySQL. The application does not connect to MySQL container from the Django Application but it can be accessed using Sequel Pro with the same credentials.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.18
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=django
      - MYSQL_USER=django
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass

  web:
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - db
#    links:
#      - db
    volumes:
      - "./app:/src"
    command: bash -c "sleep 3 && python3 src/manage.py runserver 8000"
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.production
      - DB_NAME=django
      - DB_USER=django
      - DB_PASS=pass
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
```

This is my django settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME', 'django'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER', 'django'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASS', 'pass'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'db'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
        }
    }
}
```

And this is error that I don't know how to fix this

```
web_1    | Performing system checks...
web_1    |
web_1    | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7efeb8563950>
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
web_1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 274, in get_new_connection
web_1    |     conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-
packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 86, in Connect
web_1    |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 204, in __init__
web_1    |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
web_1    | _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (110)")
```

Please advice I don't know what I do mistake.

Update: I just see that my container can't send request to sentry.io too

```
Sentry responded with an error: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution> (url: https://sentry.io/api/210137/store/)
```

So This is about docker network? How do I investigate this problem thanks

Comment: Try doing a 'docker exec' into the django container and then try doing some DNS troubleshooting: What does `dig db. @127.0.0.11` return?

Comment: `dig google.com`, `dig db`, `dig db. @127.0.0.11`  connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the containers to the same network:

```
version: '2' 
services:
  db: 
    image: mysql:5.7.18
    ...
    networks:
    - base
  web: 
    ...
    networks:
    - base
networks:
  base:
```

Comment: the containers are already on the same default network in the example that was originally given.

Comment: not work, and because by default docker will create default network.

Comment: try entering the django container and check if you can reach manually mysql

Comment: I exec to my web container and `dig google.com`, `dig db` it tell `connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Comment: I think you are having networking issues at the host level. Try restarting the docker service in order to get your iptables settings reconfigured

Comment: I try to restart docker service, and reinstall docker it not help.